# Difference Between Maven Integrated in Eclipse and Maven from maven.org Website

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, environment, integrated

Is the Maven instance that's installed separately (from the maven.org website) different than the one integrated in an Eclipse installation?  If so, could I add the correct environmental variables to make the system look at both instances in order to run a project on either instance?

Comment: The version number should be decisive. Java, eclipse, maven, and plugin versions.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-09 contains Maven 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

The Maven2Eclipse plugin is initially configured with an "embedded" Maven distribution, which is used by default.  In the "Maven" section of the Eclipse Preferences, and the "Installations" sub-tab, you can see which Maven distributions Eclipse knows about. You can add additional ones, and you can change which one M2E uses for its builds by checking each distribution.